# How do I create a bootable drive from a partition using Clonezilla?

Tags: windows-server-2008, boot, clone, clonezilla

I have a 500GB HDD with two partitions on it. A 40 GB OS partition (Windows Server 2008 R2), and a 420GB data partition.

I would like to split these partitions off to two physical drives. (A 120GB SSD and a 1TB HDD)

My issue is, when I use Clonezilla to copy the OS partition to an image, and then restore that image, it is not bootable. As far as I can tell, I can't make a bootable partition copy.

SO, considering these extenuating circumstances, what is the best way for me to split these drives?

Comment: Is the partitioning GPT or MBR?

Answer (score 0):

Just use windows server backup.

1) Restore just the OS partition to the ssd
2) Restore the Data partition to hdd

If you are short of a backup destination do it the following way.

1) Backup to the 1TB drive and restore to the SSD, just the OS
2) Use clonezilla to clone the data partition, or even something like unstoppable copier at this point. (If you are going to copy do it in safe mode to ensure no data is in use and will be copied)

Comment: I was looking into Windows Server Backup, but I wasn't sure at how sophisticated the volume remapping would be during restoration. 

So you're saying if I backup to a 3rd drive, I can pull the original 500GB HDD, then boot up Windows install disc with the SDD and new Data HDD in place, and restore the backup images to the different drives without issue?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Do exactly that, there is a button to exclude drives on the restore. Which will allow you to do the above

Comment: OK, I'm running into an issue. I'm never given the option to choose what partitions go onto what new drives. I just get an error about not having the drives I need to restore the image.

Comment: Using System Image Recovery, I select the latest backup and choose "Only restore system drives"
After hitting Next, I get the confirmation screen that Ids the date of the backup the system name, and the "Drives to Restore" where it lists \\?\Volume{long id string], C:

If I hit "Finish" I get the following error:
"Windows did not find any disk which it can use for recreating volumes present in backup. Offline disks, cluster shared disks or disks explicitly excluded by user will not be used Windows."

At no point am I given the option to direct the old C: volume to the new SSD.

Comment: This is a problem with Drivers, you need to add drivers so the restore process can detect your new drives. See step 7 here http://www.wbadmin.info/articles/howto-bare-metal-restores-windows-server-2008-backup.html

Comment: I can't find info on Drivers for the SSD anywhere. (Samsung 850 EVO) They CD that came with it is just a manual and some "Install Navigator" software that won't run inside the Restore utility.

Comment: You need drivers for the storage controller. So check who makes the server you are plugging the drives into

Comment: So I ended up buying Migrate OS to SSD for $20 and I got it all resolved in about 30 minutes. I wish I had found it earlier.

Thanks for your help, though.